# Leave tableView on row selection

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, tvos

I am trying to make an TableView inside of a ViewController working as a picker.

Its a simple Table View with o e textlabel.

My Problem is, that i cant leave the tableview on go on to the next textfield.

I have tried it with this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    [_textfield becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

but that only open the keyboard and after i make the input i am back in the tableview.

What must i do to leave the tableview when i select a row?

Image from the storyboard.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Objective-C

You need to keep track of and update the `preferredFocusView` of you `UITableViewCell` subclass depending on whether the cell has been selected and what the `UIFocusHeading`is.

The first thing you should do is add a property on your `UITableViewCell` subclass to keep track of the current subview you'd like to have focused. For example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *currentPreferredFocusedSubview;
```

Then in your view controller in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you should set that to the text field you would like focused and then request the focus engine to update:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
    cell.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = cell.textField;
    [cell setNeedsFocusUpdate];
}
```

Now in your `UITableViewCell` subclass you need to return your preferred focus view and change how the focus engine updates by overriding `preferredFocusedView` and `shouldUpdateFocusInContext`:

```
- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView
{
    return self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview;
}

- (BOOL)shouldUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context
{
    if (self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview == self.textField && context.focusHeading == UIFocusHeadingRight)
    {
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = self.textField2;
    }
    else if (self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview == self.textField2 && context.focusHeading == UIFocusHeadingRight)
    {
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = self.textField3;
    }
    else if (self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview == self.textField3 && context.focusHeading == UIFocusHeadingRight)
    {
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = self.textField3;
    }
    else if (self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview == self.textField3 && context.focusHeading == UIFocusHeadingLeft)
    {
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = self.textField2;
    }
    else if (self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview == self.textField2 && context.focusHeading == UIFocusHeadingLeft)
    {
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = self.textField;
    }
    else if (self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview == self.textField && context.focusHeading == UIFocusHeadingLeft)
    {
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = self.textField;
    }
    else
    {
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = nil;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here we just update the `preferredFocusedView` based on the direction the focus engine is going. If going up or down, the next row will become focused because we're returning `nil`. If left or right, the appropriate text fields. This is somewhat clunky but this is the tvOS 9 way of programmatically updating the focus view.

### Swift

```
var currentPreferredFocusedSubview: UITextField?
    
override var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    get{
        return self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview
    }
}

override func shouldUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool {
    switch (self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview, context.focusHeading) {
    case (self.textField?, UIFocusHeading.Right):
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = self.textField2
    case (self.textField2?, UIFocusHeading.Right):
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = self.textField3
    case (self.textField3?, UIFocusHeading.Right):
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = self.textField3
    case (self.textField3?, UIFocusHeading.Left):
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = self.textField2
    case (self.textField2?, UIFocusHeading.Left):
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = self.textField
    case (self.textField?, UIFocusHeading.Left):
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = self.textField
    default:
        self.currentPreferredFocusedSubview = nil
    }
    return true
}
```